# Asynchronous image loading from Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, asynchronous, core-data, uicollectionview

I am building an application which uses a Core Data database to store its data on products. These products are displayed in a `UICollectionView`. Each cell in this collection view displays basic information on the product it contains, including an image.

Although the cells are relatively small, the original images they display are preferably quite large as they should also be able to be displayed in a larger image view. The images are loaded directly from Core Data in my `CellForItemAtIndexPath:` Method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionWineCell

        var current: Product!

        //product details are set on labels

        //image is set
        if current.value(forKey: "image") != nil {
            let image = current.value(forKey: "image") as! WineImage
            let loadedImage = UIImage(data: image.image)
            cell.imageview.image = loadedImage
        } else {
            cell.imageview.image = UIImage(named: "ProductPlaceholder.png")
        }

        return cell
    }
```

When the collection of products grows, scrolling gets bumpier and a lot of frames are dropped. This makes sense to me, but so far I haven't found a suitable solution. When looking online a lot of documentation and frameworks are available for asynchronous image loading from a URL (either online or a file path), but doing this from Core Data does not seem very common.

I have already tried doing it using an asynchronous fetch request:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"ProductImage")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "product = %@", current)
        let asyncRequest = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) { results in
            if let results = results.finalResult {
                let result = results[0] as! ProductImage
                let loadedImage = UIImage(data: result.image)
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    cell.wineImage.image = loadedImage
                })
            }
        }
        _ = try! managedObjectContext.executeRequest(asyncRequest)
```

However, this approach does not seems to smoothen things out either

**QUESTION**
When displaying large sets of data, including images, from Core Data, how does one load images in a way that it does not cause lags and frame drops in a `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the images can be, as you say, quite large, a better approach is not to save them in Core Data but to put them in files. Store the filename in Core Data and use that to look up the file.

But that's not the immediate problem. Even with that you'll get slowdowns from spending time opening and decoding image data. A better approach is, basically, don't do that. In your collection views the images are probably displayed much smaller than their full size. Instead of using the full size image, generate a thumbnail at a more appropriate size and use that in the collection view. Do the thumbnail generation whenever you first get the image, whether from a download or from the user's photo library or wherever. Keep the thumbnail for use in the collection view. Only use the full size image when you really need it.

There are many examples online of how to scale images, so I won't include that here.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will implement this in my application and will get back to you tomorrow at latest!

Comment: I have implemented what you said in my project. My images also generate smaller thumbnails when created and/or received, and these are loaded asynchronously in the images (using NUKE) of the collection view causing scrolling to be smoother. You answer has helped me to a point where I can continue my project without worrying about this and I thank you for that.